# Signing ClickOnce application with code signing certificate, but publisher still unknown

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, clickonce, code-signing-certificate

I have 2 code signing certificates, for both `CSR` is created same way, also import and export is done same way. The only difference that I see is that one of certificates `Common name` contains Quotes, and the other doesn't.

e.g. 
`some cert` and
`some "cert"`

**CSR creation**

- Request format PKCS #10
- disabled "Strong private key encryption"
- Entered Common name, Organization, Locality, State, Country
- 2048 bytes for private key
- set private key exportable

**Import**

- place all certificates in Personal store

**Export**

- Include all certificates if possible
- Enable certificate privacy
- encryption algorithm TripleDES-SHA1

Misleading thing is that this `Common name` value is NOT taken from the value I entered when I created `CSR` request

I am using those certificates to sign `Winforms` applications in `Visual Studio`. Certificate without Quotes in `common name` is working correctly (i.e. when I install application user is not getting security warning about `unknown publisher`), but when I install application which is signed with the other Code signing certificate (with Quotes in `Common name`) - it does not recognize `Publisher`. No error when published my application. When I take a look at `setup.exe` properties in `Windows Explorer` I see a `Digital signatures` tab which contains row for my certificate.

I tried to sign files with signtool and then verify - it said that certificate is valid.

I tried to get help from godaddy.com where I bought my certificate, they said that it should work with quotes, too, but didn't offer help to solve the issue. `Rekey` also didn't help.

I see that there are some suggestions to use Pre Publish, Post Build tasks, but I am not using those for my first certificate which is working.

So, is anyone here using code signing certificate for `Winforms` application with `common name` having quotes in it? Or maybe anyone knows about this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to revoke (`common name` which is entered when creating CSR is **not** taken into account, so rekeying is not enough!) my code signing certificate and create from start **without quotes/brackets in company name**.

So this means, you will have to wait again for few days, because verification process is made from start again. When you will be contacted by issuer, they will verify / ask you about company name - make sure that they **do not include** quotes/brackets.

Revoking means that you will basically have to buy your certificate once more, because after you revoke it (at least in godaddy case) in your account you don't have options to create it again. So, you have to contact support (use call center and not chat ;)

Comment: P.S. Just for information - when discussing this topic with support over phone it *was* possible to get new certificate without paying for the second time. But support personnel from chat I did not manage to negotiate about it, although this person actually suggested to revoke my certificate in the first place…